# Showing sum of conditions as one row

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Hi I have a table like this

```
select id, value, condition from mytable
```

result

[image]

and I need a query to make it like this

[image]

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when condition = 'true' then value else 0 end) as num_true,
       sum(case when condition = 'false' then value else 0 end) as num_false
from t
group by id;
```

You have tagged the question with both Oracle and SQL Server.  Neither supports a boolean type directly in SQL, so I am guessing that the condition is a string.

Comment: This is a very common question asked by user he just need to do little research over net. Hence it should be closed.

Comment: @smn_onrocks : Are you sure if it's "he"  :) ?

Comment: omg! i wasted 3 hours for this. i thought i tried your solution at the start

Answer (score 1):

yes possible

```
select id "id", sum(decode(condition,'TRUE',value,0))  "sum_of_condition_true", 
                sum(decode(condition,'FALSE',value,0)) "sum_of_condition_false"
  from mytable
 group by id
 order by id;
```